# Redirect to requested page after login using vue-router

Tags: redirect, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In my application some routes are just accessible for authenticated users.
When a unauthenticated user clicks on a link, for which he has to be signed in, he will be redirected to the login component.
If the user logs in successfully, **I would like to redirect him to the URL he requested before he had to log in**. However, **there also should be a default route**, in case the user did not request another URL before he logged in.
**How can I achieve this using vue-router?**

---

**My code without redirect after login**

```js
router.beforeEach(
    (to, from, next) => {
        if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
            next()
        } else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)) {
            if(!Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                next({
                    path: '/login'
                    // Redirect to original path if specified
                })
            } else {
                next()
            }
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }        
)
```

**My login function in my login component**

```js
login() {
    var data = {
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: '**************',
        grant_type: 'password',
        username: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }
    // send data
    this.$http.post('oauth/token', data)
         .then(response => {
             // authenticate the user
             this.$auth.setToken(response.body.access_token,
             response.body.expires_in + Date.now())
             // redirect to route after successful login
             this.$router.push('/')
          })
}
```

Comment: You could do something like `next({ path: '/login?from=' + to.path })` and then check on your login page if the `from` query param is set and do a redirect

Comment: @FlorianHaider That sounds like a great solution! How can I check if the from query param is set from my login component?

Comment: @Schwesi you get the query parameters using `this.$route.query.from`. If there is no query present you get an empty object

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 93, accepted):

This can be achieved by adding the **redirect path** in the route as a [query parameter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

Then when you login, you have to check if the redirect parameter is set:

- if **IS** set redirect to the path found in param
- if is **NOT** set you can fallback on root.

---

**Put an action to your link for example:**

```js
onLinkClicked() {
    if(!isAuthenticated) {
        // If not authenticated, add a path where to redirect after login.
        this.$router.push({ name: 'login', query: { redirect: '/path' } });
    }
}
```

**The login submit action:**

```js
submitForm() {
    AuthService.login(this.credentials)
        .then(() => this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || '/'))
        .catch(error => { /*handle errors*/ })
}
```

Comment: @V how do you do this when you have a 3rd party login, e.g. for a google account auth the user is redirected to a different link i.e the 3rd party vendor link to login and then back to our app?

Comment: @JasbindarSingh : set returnUrl param to redirect link of 3rd party

Comment: Works perfectly in Vuejs 3 `<script setup>`. Thanks.

Answer (score 41):

I know this is old but it's the first result in google and for those of you that just want it given to you this is what you add to your two files. In my case I am using firebase for auth.

### Router

The key line here is `const loginpath = window.location.pathname;` where I get the relative path of their first visit and then the next line `next({ name: 'Login', query: { from: loginpath } });` I pass as a query in the redirect.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

    if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
        const loginpath = window.location.pathname;
        next({ name: 'Login', query: { from: loginpath } });
    } else if (!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('menu');
    else next();
});
```

### Login Page

No magic here you'll just notice my action upon the user being authenticated `this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.from);` it sends them to the query url we generated earlier.

```js
signIn() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password).then(
        (user) => {
            this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.from);
        },
        (err) => {
            this.loginerr = err.message;
        },
    );
},
```

I am going to be fleshing out this logic in more detail but it works as is. I hope this helps those that come across this page.

Comment: worked for me, great answer... I was trying a lot of other ways to solve this problem, like store the url in localstorage etc.. but this is a neat and the right way to to auth redirects

Comment: I think this is the most general solution, but I needed to refine it further. I wasn't able to simply do `$router.replace` on `window.location.pathname`, which includes the entire URL (`http://...`). I needed to get `window.location.hash` and strip the leading `#/` before setting the `from` query param. Of course, I'm using vue-router in hash mode... will need different tweaking for history mode. The answer should be clarified with these details.

Comment: If you're using [FirebaseUI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui) for your auth, you can define the redirect URL like this `const redirectUrl = to.redirectedFrom;`, then easily [overwrite the sign in success URL](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#overwriting-the-sign-in-success-url) with `next({ name: "Sign Up", query: { "mode": "popup", "signInSuccessUrl": redirectUrl } });`.

Comment: I think that this answer is better then the marked one. I find more elegant using `to.path` instead of `window.location.pathname`, has it any drawback?

Comment: `to.path` didn't work for me as I had query params, `to.fullPath` works better

Answer (score 10):

Following on from Matt C's answer, this is probably the simplest solution but there were a few issues with that post, so I thought it best to write a complete solution.

The destination route can be stored in the browser's session storage and retrieved after authentication. The benefit of using session storage over using local storage in this case is that the data doesn't linger after a broswer session is ended.

In the router's beforeEach hook set the destination path in session storage so that it can be retrieved after authentication. This works also if you are redirected via a third party auth provider (Google, Facebook etc).

**router.js**

// If user is not authenticated, before redirecting to login in beforeEach

```
sessionStorage.setItem('redirectPath', to.path)
```

So a fuller example might look something like this. I'm using Firebase here but if you're not you can modify it for your purposes:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(x => x.meta.requiresAuth);
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  if (requiresAuth && !currentUser) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('redirectPath', to.path);
    next('/login');
  } else if (requiresAuth && currentUser) {
    next();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

**login.vue**

In your login method, after authetication you will have a line of code that will send the user to a different route. This line will now read the value from session storage. Afterwards we will delete the item from session storage so that it is not accidently used in future (if you the user went directly to the login page on next auth for instance).

```
this.$router.replace(sessionStorage.getItem('redirectPath') || '/defaultpath');
sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectPath');
```

A fuller example might look like this:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'Login',
  data() {
    return {
      loginForm: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password).then(user => {

        //Go to '/defaultpath' if no redirectPath value is set
        this.$router.replace(sessionStorage.getItem('redirectPath') || '/defaultpath');

        //Cleanup redirectPath
        sessionStorage.removeItem('redirectPath');

      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: this.$router.push small correction here, i think it should be this.$router.replace because if you push you can always hit the back button and go back to the login form

Comment: This is a good point. In my particular case it wasn't an issue because my router config checks if a user is authenticated and redirects them to a default page if they attempt to go to the login page, but what you suggest is cleaner. Will update.

Answer (score 7):

If route guard is setup as below

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (!loggedIn) {
            next({
                path: "/login",
                query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

The redirect query can be extracted and used upon successful login

```js
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

if (searchParams.has("redirect")) {
  this.$router.push({ path: `${searchParams.get("redirect")}` });
} else this.$router.push({ path: "/dashboard" });
```

Answer (score 3):

Another quick and dirty option would be to use local storage like the following:

1. In your beforeEach, before you redirect to login place the following line of code to save the initial requested path to local storage:

   **router.js**
   *// If user is not authenticated, before redirecting to login*
   `localStorage.setItem('pathToLoadAfterLogin', to.path)`
2. Then in your login component, upon succesful login, you can redirect to the localStorage variable that you previously created:

   **login.vue**

   // *If user login is successful, route them to what they previously requested or some default route*
    `this.$router.push(localStorage.getItem('pathToLoadAfterLogin') || 'somedefaultroute');`

Comment: I would say that this is not just quick and dirty, but actually optimal in many situations. I was going to do it the other way, passing redirect path around as a route param, but found that this won't work for external oauth providers. When you send someone away to Google oauth they will come back without any params. If you use localStorage, this isn't an issue. (One could suggest adding a URL query param to the end of the oauth redirect URL, but most oauth providers make you specify each of these ahead of time.)

Comment: Note that if you're doing this, you will probably want to make sure you also run localStorage.setItem when there's no redirect path - in case the user leaves the site and comes back later for a different reason, we don't want to keep that redirect URL

Comment: This needs to set the to.path, not the from.path. At the moment it is returning back to the calling page. Also removing the key from local storage after executing the $router.push will prevent it from being used the next time the user authenticates if the user goes directly to the login page.

Answer (score 1):

[Much easier with this library](https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth)
and login function is

```
let redirect = this.$auth.redirect();
this.$auth
  .login({
    data: this.model,
    rememberMe: true,
    redirect: { name: redirect ? redirect.from.name : "homepage",  query: redirect.from.query },
    fetchUser: true
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you @Schwesi .

```
Router.beforeEach(
    (to, from, next) => {
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
            if (Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                next({
                    path: '/feed'
                })
            } else
                next()
        }
        else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)) {
            if (!Vue.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                next({
                    path: '/login'
                })
            } else
                next()
        } else
            next()
    }
);
```

Comment: what does next() do in this code you provided? I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
 this.axios.post('your api link', {
                token: this.token,              
            })
                .then(() => this.$router.push(this.$route.query.redirect || '/dashboard'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Vue2` if someone has a `routing` and `guarded` some groups of routes. I solved this way.

```
function webGuard(to, from, next) {
    if (!store.getters["auth/authenticated"]) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("redirect", to); // hear I save the to 
        next("/login");
    } else {
        next();
    }
}



Vue.use(VueRouter);
export default new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    hash: false,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            component: Home,
            children: [
                { path: "", redirect: "home" },
                ...
                   ...    
                ],
                beforeEnter: webGuard
        },]
```

when you login

```
this.signIn({ email: test@gmail.com, password: 123 })
        .then((res) => {
        
          var redirectPath = sessionStorage.getItem('redirect');
           sessionStorage.removeItem('redirect');
            this.$router.push(redirectPath?redirectPath:"/dashboard");
     })
```