# How to redirect to the dashboard component page after login successfully(login component) in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, vue-router, login-script

Hello I want to redirect routing my login component page to the dashboard component with successful login. I have done a response through my local API having a status code 400 & status code 200 but don't know how to redirect after the successfully login.

**Here is the component script code:**

```
    import axios from 'axios'
    export default {
      name: 'Login',
      data () {
        return {
          email: '',
          password: '',
          error: ''
        }
      },
      methods: {
        login () {
          axios.post('http://ztlab01/db-admin/app/v1/login', {
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
          }, {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'})
            .then((response) => {
              console.log(response.data)
              if (response.data.code === 400) {
                this.error = 'Invalid Credentials'
              }
              if (response.data.code === 200) {
                this.error = ''
              }
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: here i am using Vue.js so i need to redirect in a component of vue.js like Login.vue to Dashboard.vue after succefully login response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to requested page after login using vue-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856929/redirect-to-requested-page-after-login-using-vue-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `vue-router`, you should use `router.go(path)` (VueJS < 2.0) to navigate to any particular route.

The router can be accessed from within a component using `this.$router`.

`router.go()` changed in VueJS 2.0. You can use `router.push({ name: "yourroutename"})` or just `router.push("yourroutename")` now to redirect.

Otherwise, `window.location.href = 'some url';` works fine for non single-page apps.

More links to help

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html

[Vue.js redirection to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664550/vue-js-redirection-to-another-page)

Comment: need a change at a $router.push in my case..anyways thank you @Ashish451