# How can Vue component functions be made reusable?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

In a Vue application I have many features that can only be used if the user is actively logged in.

The function that checks if the user is authenticated is like this:

```
    import {useStore} from "vuex";
    import {useRoute, useRouter} from "vue-router";   
        
    export default {
     setup() {
        const VueStore = useStore();
        const VueRouter = useRouter(); 
        const route$ = useRoute();
    
        const isLoggedIn = ref(VueStore.state.securityStore.isLoggedIn);
            
            async function authenticateIdentity() {
                
                  try {
                    await VueStore.dispatch('securityStore/autoLogin');
                    if (isLoggedIn !== true) {
                      return VueRouter.push({name: "Login", query: {redirect: route$.path}})
                    }
                  } catch (error) {
                    return VueRouter.push({name: "Login", query: {redirect: route$.path}})
                  }
                }
             }
         }
```

The steps are simple:

1. Ask the `VueStore` to run an `action` that logs in the user automatically (using cookies)
2. If the authentication passed do nothing (that is, let the calling function carry on)
3. Else if not authenticated, take the user to the `Login` screen

I would like to keep this code in a separate file and use it in whichever component I need to. How can this be done in Vue3?

Comment: You can make it a composable: https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html

Comment: This logic actually belongs to router hooks and can be written once for all components. Btw `isLoggedIn !== true` is always false because it's an object. `ref(VueStore.state.securityStore.isLoggedIn)` is a mistake, this kills the reactivity of the store

Comment: @EstusFlask how do you write it once for all the components? trying out Nechoj answer at the moment but struggling with a few things like accessing the Router

Comment: router.beforeEach. This is even shown in related links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856929/redirect-to-requested-page-after-login-using-vue-router?rq=1

Comment: Instead of redirecting to the `Login` page, a better UX is to show a modal dialog and don't destroy the user's context.

Comment: @EtusFlask A beforeEach() is not appropriate. The `authenticateIdentity()` runs when an action is taken in the application, it has nothing to do with routes. The same route e.g. `/questions/777` will have a UI that lets a question be deleted/edited. If such an action is clicked, then it needs to run `authenticateIdentity()`

Comment: @Nechoj It seems that `vue-router` doesn't work in a composable. I have to create a new instance of the router in the composable JS file which doesn't affect the main router. When I tried the push method, the URL in the address bar changed but the app does not go to that view.

Comment: @volumeone you can have a seperate file `router.js` where you define your routes and use `const router = createRouter(...)` to instantiate it, then `export default router;`.  In `main.js` you would `import router from 'router.js'` as well as in your composable. This way, you use the same router both in main and your composable.

Comment: @Nechoj thank you for the pointer, now it works fine! if you post as an answer i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create a Vue3 [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) that allows to reuse the function in other places.

The tricky part is the `vue-router`. We have to make sure that the used router inside the composable is actually the same instance of the router as being used inside the App/components. We cannot use `useRouter()` which is the method for using the router inside the setup function of components (in our composable we do not have a setup function). Therefore, we suggest to put the router definition in an extra module and share this module between App and composable definitions.

##### 1. Create new file `router.js`

```
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home},
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login},
    ...
    {path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*", component: NotFound},
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes: routes
})

export default router;
```

##### 2. Use router module in `main.js`

```
import {createApp} from 'vue'
import router from './router.js'
import App from './components/App.vue'

const myApp = createApp(App);
myApp.use(router)
     .mount('#app');
```

##### 3. Create composable `loggin.js`

```
import {ref} from 'vue';
import store from './store.js';  // assuming this is the file containing the store definition
import router from './router.js';

export async function authenticateIdentity() {
    const isLoggedIn = ref(store.state.securityStore.isLoggedIn);
    try {
        await store.dispatch('securityStore/autoLogin');
        if (isLoggedIn !== true) {
            return router.push({name: "Login", query: {redirect: router.currentRoute.value.path}})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return router.push({name: "Login", query: {redirect: router.currentRoute.value.path}})
    }
}
```

##### 4. Use composable in other components

```
<script>
import {authenticateIdentity} from 'loggin.js'

export default {
  name: "LoginComponent",
  methods: {
    login(){
      authenticateIdentity().then( ... ).catch( ... );
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

(adapt project structure / import paths / names)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a plugin

```js
const myAuthPlugin = {
  install(app, options) {
    // move the Authentication logic and method here
  }
}

app.use(myAuthPlugin)
```

Comment: It turns out that a composable works just as well - see first comment on my question.